# Cabbage leaves closed

Tags: vegetables, cabbage

A cabbage plant on my pot seems to have formed a head, however I am not able to see the head completely as the cabbage **leaves have converged and closed themselves towards the head and is very much tightly stuck inwards.**

I am afraid to open the leaves by force to see the head. I suspect that the plant is dead?

I shall post a picture later, but can someone help me whether is this normal or the cabbage has any disease?

Thanks for any help on this issue.

Comment: Pictures would definitely help, especially since a cabbage head consists of closed leafs... Hard to imagine what you are meaning without pictures...

Comment: Sorry for the delays. Was out of town. Would post the picture earliest by tomo morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds completely normal for cabbage or any brassica for that matter.  As the head enlarges, the leaves surrounding it expand - kinda magic!  Not saying your plant couldn't be dead, but the enclosing leaves (bracts, actually) are a good sign, not a bad one.

Just the same, look for what look like lots of spider webs or tiny moving bodies, as major insect infestations can also cause leaves to curl together.  If bugs are bad enough to do that, you won't have to force anything open to find evidence!